# How to run a function only when scroll down near the bottom?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using [angular2-infinite-scroll](https://github.com/orizens/angular2-infinite-scroll) version 0.1.4.

My plunker is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/zqtnMi0Xmra6q0Sme9xs?p=preview).

Right it only run `onScrollDown()` one time in the beginning when you scroll.

I tried to change `infiniteScrollDistance` to `2` and `0.8`. But all failed.

How can I run `onScrollDown()` only when scroll down near the bottom?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [InfiniteScroll],
  styles: [`
    .search-results {
      height: 20rem;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
  `],
  template: `
    <div class="search-results"
         infinite-scroll
         [infiniteScrollDistance]="0.8"
         [immediateCheck]="true" 
         (scrolled)="onScrollDown()">
      <p *ngFor="let i of array">
        {{i}}
      </p>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  array = [];
  sum = 20;

  constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.sum; ++i) {
      this.array.push(i);
    }
  }

  onScrollDown () {
    console.log('near the bottom!!');

    // add another 20 items
    const start = this.sum;
    this.sum += 20;
    for (let i = start; i < this.sum; ++i) {
      this.array.push(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is onScrollDown() run on initial page load?

Comment: @AngJobs sorry, it is because of `[immediateCheck]`, I removed it. Now `onScrollDown()` won't run on initial page load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: create an observable that tracks the mouse moves and only triggers but only emits values if the mouse is near the bottom. For example:

```
const mouseMove$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
                      .filter(event => event.clientY > SOME_VALUE);
```

SOME_VALUE needs to be calculated depending on the document height.

Then create a second observable that tracks scroll events:

```
const scroll$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, "scroll");
```

Then combine both: create an observable that only emits a value if mouse is moving on the bottom of the page and the user is scrolling:

```
const combined$ = Observable.combineLatest(
    mouseMove$, scroll$
);
```

and then subscribe to it:

```
combined$.subscribe(
    combined => {
       console.log("this the mouse event", combined[0]);
       console.log("this the scroll event", combined[1]);

       // user is scrolling at the bottom of the page, add action here
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but one thing needs to improve, the 'mousemove' event won't fire when use Mac touchpad to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try an onScroll somewhere to trap the window scrolling event...something like this and then throw your function that will do whatever you want inside.

**javascript**

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    console.log("scrolling");
};
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    console.log("scrolling");
});
```

there are functions/methods too that will return the top and bottom of the window or viewport (whichever you need and if it's raw javascript, jQuery, or another framework) and then it's a math thing to do what you need at the point you want your function to kick in.

Answer (score 0):

For my issue, I need change `height: 20rem;` to `height: 100%;`, then it works. [Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2GDeeBI47LstjmWqs4e4?p=preview).

Also, @orizens added an [official demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/DzKAiAxtAleIrT0tsqtj?p=preview) in the angular2-infinite-scroll's [README.md](https://github.com/orizens/angular2-infinite-scroll) file after I asking him.

---

If you don't want to use **angular2-infinite-scroll**,
@Angular University gives a good direction using RxJS. Please check his answer.